# Scope inheritance in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to Angular, so I'm trying to follow tutorial and just don't get it.What confuses me is the dot notation:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
  <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
    <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Typing a value inside any of the input boxes will update all the other input boxes.
So, what I think that is going on here is that the first `ng-model` declaration outside controllers is binding the input element value to the data.message model in the root scope.I don't understand how the bindings inside `ng-controller` are then reading the value from the root scope, and why values  inserted inside `ng-controller` scope will be shown in a input box outside that scope?

Also if `data.` is removed

```
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="message">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>

  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="message">
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

that behavior is gone, how come?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is the recommended way to do things in Angular.  The best practice being that there should always be a dot in your `ngModel`s as using primitives in an `ngModel` is a common source of bugs in Angular.

This is discussed at length in [Angular's understand scopes document](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3
>   minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with
>   ng-switch.

But in short this is due to how Javascript's prototypal inheritance works.

**In your second example** you have a primitive type - a string for example- inside each `ngModel`.  When the `ngModel` in each controller (each on their own child scopes) tries to **read** from a primitive type they look to their parents first to see if the variable is there.  If it is then they read from it.  However when one of the `ngModels` **writes** to that primitive then a new instance of the primitive is added on it's scope.

Thus each `input` shares a common variable (the one on your top scope) at first, when only being read from, and then each `input` switches to using an independent variable once it's written to.  You can watch this in action [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2pVW/1/) by first typing in the top, parent, `input` and then in the children.

Angular recommends avoiding this since the mismatch between how reading and writing operate can clearly be very confusing and error prone

**In your first example** you're instead creating an object `data` with a property `message`.  In this case reading works just like with a primitive- it looks to find that object with that property on the parent scope and reads from it if it's there.  But this time writing works the same way as reading- if there is a parent object `data` with property `message` then the write is done to the object's property.

So, **when you use dot notation, reading and writing act consistently** as you can see [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6C8Sp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, `data` as an object is a common object between three scopes and each scope has reference to data.So when `data.message` is changed all three scope show the changed message.
But in the second case the `message` is a string witch is a value type not an object. Each scope has its own message and changing one of theme will not effect others.