# Angularjs ng-model become one way inside the kendo ui tabstrip

Tags: angularjs, tabs, kendo-ui

I am using angularjs+kendoui for a small project. (I am learning angularjs)

However I found that ng-model only work one way (it can populate from controller/model to UI) but when I change the UI, it can't populate the model.

Below is a simple example.

I have a text box inside the tab. When I update the text, the model was not updated.
I have another text box outside the tab. When I update the text, the model was updated.
see the sample below
http://plnkr.co/edit/tknizoUTtheuOoAUZv4E?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo directive create a new scope. You need to have '.' in your ng-model. It is recommended.

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($compile, $scope) {
$scope.o = {};
 $scope.o.testText = 'hello'
$scope.o.testText2 = 'hello2'
});
```

**and in your view**

```
<div id="tabstrip" kendo-tab-strip>
  <ul>
    <li class="k-state-active">Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
  </ul>

  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="o.testText" />
  </div>
  <div>
    [Page 2]
  </div>
</div>
    <div>
    <span>Tab Text </span></span><p>{{o.testText}}</p>

    </div>
    <span>Outside Tab Text </span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="o.testText2" />
    <p>{{o.testText2}}</p>

  </body>
```

You can find more detail about this feature of angular in 
[Scope inheritance in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870623/scope-inheritance-in-angular/20871057#20871057)