# How to clear text from AngularUI typeahead input

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I have a typeahead input. The input text is set to the option selected on the typeahead. However, I want to clear this text and display the "placeholder" value again on the text box after I select one of the options from typeahead (because I add the selected value to another div in the `selectMatch()` method.

```
<input id="searchTextBoxId" type="text" 
    ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search  addresses..."
    typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
    typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control"
    typeahead-on-select="selectMatch(asyncSelected)" typeahead-min-length="3"
    typeahead-wait-ms="500">
```

I tried to set the text value and the placeholder value of the Input element using its Id but that did not work, such as these:

```
// the input text was still the 
$('#searchTextBoxId').attr('placeholder', 'HELLO');
```

selected result

```
// the input text was still the selected result
$('#searchTextBoxId').val('');
```

How can I set or reset the text value ?

Comment: Wanted something similar , 3 years after you :D

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I was looking for an answer to this as well, for the longest time. I finally found a resolution that worked for me.

I ended up setting the NgModel to an empty string *within* the `typeahead-on-select` attribute:

---

In your `typeahead-on-select` attribute add `asyncSelected = '';` behind your select function, like so:

```html
<input ...
    typeahead-on-select="selectMatch(asyncSelected); asyncSelected = '';" />
```

Making your final typeahead looking something like:

```
<input id="searchTextBoxId" type="text" 
    ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Search  addresses..."
    typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
    typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control"
    typeahead-on-select="selectMatch(asyncSelected); asyncSelected = '';" 
    typeahead-min-length="3"
    typeahead-wait-ms="500">
```

---

<kbd>[Fiddle adding each selection to an array](https://jsfiddle.net/jnthnjns_/hw0poq93/1/)</kbd>

Comment: That's interesting. I was going down the path of clearing it within the select function and then invoking $apply to refresh. This is mch more elegant. I always feel icky invoking the apply or digest

Comment: Ugh. Lame it had to work like this. I was looking at element even.

Comment: It's a nice solution, but I'd add `value="{{selectedValue}}"` there. Without it input would become empty right after the selection (because of `asyncSelected = ''`), it would look quite strange

Comment: @JohnDoe The point of the question was to clear the input, in some cases this is needed, it makes it easier on the end user to do quick searching. I personally ran into this when I built an application for my employer where he wanted to quickly search for employee records. So I had the input clear after each search and then had a header tag with the bound result.

Comment: @Asok Ok, I had a different use-case, so I will not update your answer

Comment: @Asok Thank you so much for this asnwer.  I tried clearing the value inside of the typahead-on-select method but this didn't work for some strange reason...

Comment: @jnthnjns Your fiddle links not working. Can you please update them.

Comment: @rohit Recreated the fiddle. Sorry about that and sorry to get back to you so late

Answer (score 10):

Actually this problem is not from typeahead. It is common issue about `ng-model, scope and dot notation`.

Refer 
[Scope inheritance in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870623/scope-inheritance-in-angular)

At your situation, you just change the model name like as `xx.selected` with dot-notation and set xx.selected empty in typeahead-on-select callback.

Answer (score 2):

To set or reset the value, wouldn't you access the ng-model value, which is asyncSelected according to your code?  In a controller:

```
$scope.asyncSelected = '';
```

Comment: Thanks Reboog711. No that did not work, as in the text is not being cleared from the input element.

Answer (score 0):

[@Asok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23248401/1449799) is fine if you need to immediately clear the value, but for myself, and perhaps others who come here based on the question title, [@hey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26793276/1449799) may be better (if terse).

I changed the typeahead as follows:

```
<input id="searchTextBoxId" type="text" 
    ng-model="myNewVar.asyncSelected" placeholder="Search  addresses..."
    typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
    typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control"
    typeahead-on-select="selectMatch(myNewVar.asyncSelected)" typeahead-min-length="3"
    typeahead-wait-ms="500">
```

then, whenever i need to clear the input from my controller, i can call

```js
$scope.myNewVar.asyncSelected = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was already doing as [jnthnjns's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23248401/3063706) suggested and setting the ng-model's value to an empty string, but the selection popup was not going away because I was (intentionally) using `typeahead-min-length="0"` so that users could easily see the choices.

It wasn't until I noticed that hitting enter to make a selection actually dismissed the box and it was only on clicks that the box remained. Digging into the ui-typeahead code I saw

```
// return focus to the input element if a match was selected via a mouse click event
// use timeout to avoid $rootScope:inprog error
if (scope.$eval(attrs.typeaheadFocusOnSelect) !== false) {
   $timeout(function() { element[0].focus(); }, 0, false);
}
```

As soon as I set `typeahead-focus-on-select="false"` then the box dismisses immediately upon selection (and clearing of the model). It seems obvious now, but I had seen that option before but had read it as automatically selecting on focus (or something like that). Putting this as an answer, just in case it helps someone else.